# How can I make a today alert display all of the information I need?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, today-extension

I'm using Forismatic API to get a random inspirational quote whidh I'd like to show as a widget. I have it set up, and I have a button that generates a new quote, however I cannot get it to always display a quote/author. It seems that it's due to the length of the quote, and it running off of the constraints I've set. The error I get is:

> Error parsing json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid
>   escape sequence around character 54."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character
>   54.}

Also, how can I get the text to display starting at the top left corner?

The quotes are displaying like this, starting more in the middle of the entire label area, not the top left:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with your views/constraints - it means that there was an unexpected character in your JSON payload, and the system couldn't parse it. Without seeing the payload it is inpossible to say what this character might be.

As to placing the text in the top - there is no way to specify vertical alignement in `UILabel`. You can achieve this by setting the labels bottom constraint to be greater than or equal to 0 ( or some margin value ). This will stick the label to the top, and let it grow to accomodate more text.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the label.  I'm new to this stuff, where could I view the JSON payload?

Comment: Well, best way would be to use some kind of a proxy. But since you are using an outside service, I'd try contacting them about this.